Can you build up statistical validity with multiple month's worth of the same survey questions?
The company I work for conduct consulting where we analyse company survey responses for statistical validity against the general company population.
To prevent survey fatigue, the company sends out surveys to different sample groups each month.
My question is, because the overall questions are the same over 2 months, can you build up the statistical validity i.e. can 12% response rate in one month where 750 surveys are sent out and 12% in the next (again with 750 surveys) equal a total of a 12% response over the course of 1500 surveys?
The idea being that 1500 surveys with a 12% response rate is much healthier for determining a positive confidence level and margin of error compared to a 12% response rate for 750.
Any thoughts and best practices here would be much appreciated,
Thanks!

If you have no reason to suspect that the responses should be different between the two months (i.e., there was no policy change between month 1 and month 2 that would cause people to respond differently), then I see no reason why you can't combine the results (also assuming the sample groups are different, which you say they are). Just be careful about what you define your "population of interest" to be
